# shutting down hasn't finished (2.1)

Tags: htc-desire, 2.1-eclair

my battery was getting flat so HTC Desire 2.1 decided to shut down. That's fine but the shutting down never finished.

Put it on charger. And when clicking Power Off nothing happens. The phone is slow to operate.

Is there anything else I can do except taking the battery off?

Comment: I would remove the battery at this point.

Comment: well I did so but is there anything else I can do to fix that or even prevent from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Desire always did this, I have no idea what caused it, I always just ripped the battery out, it didn't seem to do any harm. Upgrading to Froyo fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I plan to upgrade. Let us see

Comment: no problem with that issue on cm7 any more

Answer (score 2):

A while back I read something that suggested this problem could be caused by a dodgy SD card. The suggested fix that seemed to work for me was to unmount the SD card and then power off. I have since bought a new SD card and the problem has gone away entirely.

Comment: I tried to unmount the SD card and it did not help. I hope Mr.Froyo will help ....